# Measure low AC Power consumption (oscilloscope? MCU?)

Tags: ac, current-measurement, low-power, power-consumption, power-measurement

I would like to measure AC power consumption of devices such as AC/DC charger, AC LED bulb or an electric circuit in the main box of a house.

However, their power consumption are quite low and the cosinus phi is not always usable to compute power consumption while this kind of devices does not have a proper sinus wave form.

How can I measure such consumption? Currently I have AC/AC adapter to have the voltage measurement and a clamp on amperemeter for the current. But I need to perform some calculations to determine the true power.

How can I do that? Is there a dedicated MCU or can I perform this with an oscilloscope?

Comment: Do all devices cause a phase lag? Simple incandescent lights for example?

Comment: Youtuber BigClive: https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCtM5z2gkrGRuWd0JQMx76qA uses a HOPI for that: https://nl.aliexpress.com/item/HOPI-HP-9800-Handheld-Power-Meter-Power-Analyzer-LED-Metering-Socket-Measurable-Current-voltage-Power-Factor/32375959317.html  sure you could also use an oscilloscope to measure this but that's complicated, you would need an (isolated) high voltage probe and a current transformer or such. The HOPI is a much simpler solution.

Comment: What kind of accuracy do you need?

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie You shouldn't answer questions in the comment field.

Comment: I need a accuracy for low power consumption of about 0.2 W. I appreciate the aliexpress solution but i need the 8173 version if i understand. I dont see any accuracy. Have you got an idea?